# Convert a Vector of Strings to the Rvalue of an Assignement Statement

Tags: string, vector, rvalue

I cant think of an efficient way to convert a vector of strings to become the rvalue of an assignment statement. So for example, i have a vector with three elements "5", "*", "3" so what I need is an assignment statement that is basically equivalent to the following

```
int myInteger = 5 * 3;
```

Thanks in advance;

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you know the order of variables or can determine the order of variables as well as order of operators. I would also assume, since you are using a vector, that there can be multiple variables (isn't the the point :)).

Given that, you would simply need to cast your variables and write the logic to apply operators in the correct order (as specified by your language's operator precedence).

Suppose we are using Javascript ([see precedence here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence)). For simplicity we'll only handle the multiplication, division, addition, and subtraction operators.

```
<script>
var foo = 5*4+16/2-3*2; //should be 22
var bar = ["5","*","4","+","16","/","2","-","3","*","2"];
var done = parseVec(bar); //should calculate to 22

//there are no vectors in javascript, so we'll go with an array to demonstrate
//all parsing assumes that values in the array are in decimal, not octal or hex
function parseVec (array) {
  var result, i, h, j, action;
  var newarray = [];
  
  //decision based on order of operations...all multiplication will happen 
  //first, then division, then addition, etc...
  if (array.indexOf("*") > 0 && array.indexOf("*") < (array.length-1)) {
    i = array.indexOf("*");
    action = "*";
  } else if (array.indexOf("/") > 0 && array.indexOf("*/") < (array.length-1)) {
    i = array.indexOf("/");
    action = "/";
  } else if (array.indexOf("+") > 0 && array.indexOf("+") < (array.length-1)) {
    i = array.indexOf("+");
    action = "+";
  } else if (array.indexOf("-") > 0 && array.indexOf("-") < (array.length-1)) {
    i = array.indexOf("-");
    action = "-";
  } else
    return useParseFloat(array[0]) ? parseFloat(array[0], 10) : parseInt(array[0], 10);
  
  //operate on the value preceding and following array[i]...
  h = useParseFloat(array[i-1]) ? parseFloat(array[i-1], 10) : parseInt(array[i-1], 10);
  j = useParseFloat(array[i+1]) ? parseFloat(array[i+1], 10) : parseInt(array[i+1], 10);
  switch (action)
  {
    case "*":
        result = h * j;
        break;
    case "/":
        result = h / j;
        break;
    case "+":
        result = h + j;
        break;
    case "-":
        result = h - j;
        break;
  }
  
  //recreate the array for recursion
  for(var i2 = 0; i2 < array.length; i2++)
  {
    if (i2 == i)
      newarray.push(result.toString());
    else if (i2 != (i-1) && i2 != (i+1))
      newarray.push(array[i2]);
  }
  return parseVec(newarray);
}

//should I parse this as an int or float?
function useParseFloat(val) {
  return (val.indexOf(".") >= 0 && val.indexOf(".") < (val.length-1)) ? true : false;
}
</script>
```

You can [run this code on JSBin](http://jsbin.com/welcome/28287/edit).

This should give you a fair idea of how to accomplish your given task. With a bit of play and tinkering, you can include support for most operators as well as parenthesis.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed reply, I will have to read it carefully to understand (especially that I dont know any Java at all :) ), I was thinking in the lines of concatenating all the elements of the vector into one string. and then find a way to transform that string into an rvalue. I should also mention that the order of the operations will always follow the indexing of the vector and that parentheses are also there.

Comment: You're essentially writing a run-time compiler, which needs to pick through the string to figure out what operations to perform on the given operands. By concatenating the vector into a string, you'll just have to parse it back out to operators and operands. It's actually faster to leave it be the way it is.

Answer (score 0):

You must parse element by element. Let's suppose you know that your vector will have three elements(strings), so you could do:

```
vector<string> v = {"5","*", "3"};
int x, y;
char c;
stringstream(a);
string T = v[0]+v[1]+v[2];
a << T;
a >> x >> c >> y;
```

and now you should just check what operation is in c and perform it.